# ASP.NET SignalR not disconnecting idle clients

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

When my clients goes idle without terminating the connection, the ASP.NET SignalR server doesn't close the connection and disconnect the client.

I have a ClientTimeoutInterval of 10 seconds and a KeepAliveInterval of 3 seconds.
My client can stay idle for hours and will not be disconnected.

What could be the cause of this? Surely there's a way to terminate idle clients...

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
});
```

Comment: How are the settings on the client does the client send KeepAlive's in time? The Client timeout is the time where if the server recieves a KeppAlive it will reconnect the client, but I think i had an issue a while ago where if you set the interval to lower than 30 seconds it would ignore that. That said this has been fixed for me since .net 5.

Comment: It could take longer than this timeout interval for the client to be marked disconnected due to how this is implemented. according to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=javascript#configure-server-options

Comment: But that is so useless (not being able to definitely know when clients are "kicked"). I have a real-time scenario where I need to disconnect clients quickly when they're not responding. This is a turn based game and I can't let the opponents wait forever.

Comment: I don't understand why the client implementation has any relevance here. The clients are mobile and when they minimize the app, the signal r client no longer sends keep alives, but they remain connected.

Comment: You could try add the codes to disconnect on your client side if you want it disconnect immediately

Comment: I don't want it to disconnect immediately of course. I want it to disconnect after x seconds of inactivity. In my mind this seems pretty reasonable to ask for haha...

Anyways, i created my own keep alive service and hub methods to deal with this.